# Es la primera que uso Mysql Workbench en mac

Tags: mysql-workbench

Error 1558 - Error loading schema content, ese la primera vez que estoy usando una mac, espero alguien me pueda ayudar a solucionar lo gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: "19:34:36 Error loading schema content Error Code: 1558 Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100428. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error 
"
Ese es el error que me sale, al parecer no reconoce las tablas o algo por el estilo, estoy usand XAMPP para la conexion y eso el puerto 3307

Comment: Un error que te sale al intentar hacer... ¿qué?. ¿Ejecutaste el comando que te sugieren (`mysql_upgrade`).

Comment: al intentar conectar workbench con el servidor de xampp no me sale las tablas de la base de datos, si lo ejecute pero me sale error, nose si lo abre puesto mal o se debe añadir algo mas al comando

Comment: En la terminal, tienes que ir a la carpeta de archivos de XAMPP ejecutando este comando: `cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin` y una vez allí escribes este otro comando: `sudo ./mysql_upgrade` te pedirá la contraseña y empezará a hacer el upgrade. No hagas nada hasta que no termine.

Comment: "FATAL ERROR: Could not open or create the upgrade info file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql_upgrade_info' in the MariaDB Servers data directory, errno: 13 (Permission denied)
Note that mysql_upgrade should be run as the same user as the MariaDB server binary, normally 'mysql' or 'root'.
Alternatively you can use mysql_upgrade --force --force. Please check the documentation if you decide to use the force option!" gracias por ayudarme sino fuese por el error no me salia

Comment: **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_upgrade --force --force ;** este es el comando completo que me funciono Gracias